# SubQuery with IN or INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

```
Table:  SignUp                               Table:  Thinker2014

+----------+------------+                +-----+------------+----------+
| User_Id  | Product_No |                | Id  | Product_No |  Pic_One |
+----------+------------+                +-----+------------+----------+
|    2     | HP74BK;HEW |                |  1  | HP74BK;HEW | hew1.jpg |
+----------+------------+                +-----+------------+----------+
|    9     | LC41C;HEW  |                |  2  | HP74BC;HEW | hew1.jpg |
+----------+------------+                +-----+------------+----------+
|   13     | BC21M;HEW  |                |  3  | HP74M;HEW  | hew1.jpg |
+----------+------------+                +-----+------------+----------+
|   24     | HP74Y;HEW  |                |  4  | HP74Y;HEW  | hew1.jpg |
+----------+------------+                +-----+------------+----------+
```

A customer will Login their:
UserName:  jason  and Password:  123

goto:  inks-etc.com -> Login -> submit above info -> click next page

I would like to received 4 "LIKE" products a customer have received.  In example:
If a customer has received HP74BK;HEW as a product to "ADD to CART"; I would like
to place the HP 74 Cyan, HP 74 Magenta, and HP 74Yellow as a cusotmers additional 
choice to purchase.

I have received the customer UserId of "2" as they login their username.  Then I use
that in a subquery to get the product_no that need with the TABLE: SignUp and IN
the Product_No with the TABLE: Thinker2014 that has allow other products I need. 
I have already tried INNER JOINING but I have had a hard time subquerying with
the $user_id

Here is the Sequel I need help with:
the query has the SELECT of Product that is needed with a picture of the product.
The two tables: the SignUp holds the customers product they want to buy and the
Thinker2014 stores the product they want to buy; and I am trying to IN or INNER
JOIN them to not only get the one product they need but extra "LIKE" products on
the side they may need like the different colors (cyan, mag, yellow) of ink cartridge.

```
<?php
include "../../SearchEngine/dbc_site.php";
$user_id = $_SESSION['uid'];

$query = "SELECT `Thinker2014`.`Product_No`,`Thinker2014`.`miniImageFarm`
          FROM `Thinker2014`
          WHERE `Product_No` LIKE `SignUp`.`Product_No`
          IN
             (SELECT `Product_No`
              FROM `SignUp`
              WHERE $user_id)
          LIMIT 4";

$result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $miniImage = $row['miniImageFarm'];
    $Product_No = $row['Product_No'];
?>
  <tr>
    <td>
       <table>
          <tr>
             <td><img src="<?php echo $miniImage ?>" alt="" name="miniImage"
             border="0"/></td>
                <td><?php echo $Product_No ?></td>
           </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php
}  // End of SECOND while loop
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly, then you are wanting to suggest other products that are in different colors (that match the first 4 characters of product_no for a certain user_id).

so what the below query does is it selects products from `Thinker2014` that are different from `product_no` of that user_id but is LIKE the (first 4 characters and ending with wildcard `%`) of `product_no` of that user_id

```
SELECT Product_No,miniImageFarm
FROM Thinker2014
WHERE Product_No != (SELECT Product_No FROM SignUp WHERE User_Id = $user_id)
  AND Product_No LIKE (SELECT CONCAT(LEFT(Product_No,4),'%') FROM SignUp WHERE User_Id = $user_id)
LIMIT 4
```

see this [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/64a32/1/0)

This will work so long as there's only one entry for each `user_id` in in `signup` table.  If a `user_id` has more than one entry in `signup` table, you'll have to decide which entry you want maybe by some sort of ordering based on an auto_incremented column in `signup` table like below (notice the `ORDER BY someIdColumn DESC LIMIT 1`)

```
SELECT Product_No,miniImageFarm
FROM Thinker2014
WHERE Product_No != (SELECT Product_No FROM SignUp WHERE User_Id = $user_id ORDER BY someIdColumn DESC LIMIT 1)
  AND Product_No LIKE (SELECT CONCAT(LEFT(Product_No,4),'%') FROM SignUp WHERE User_Id = $user_id ORDER BY someIdColumn DESC LIMIT 1)
LIMIT 4
```

If you wanted to use INNER JOIN as a solution, you could JOIN based on the first 4 characters of Product_No by using `LEFT(Product_No,4)` like below (this version won't break if there are 2 or more entries for a certain user_id in signup table)

```
SELECT T.Product_No,T.miniImageFarm
FROM Thinker2014 T
INNER JOIN SignUp S ON LEFT(T.Product_No,4) = LEFT(S.Product_No,4)
WHERE T.Product_No != S.Product_No
  AND S.User_Id = $user_id
LIMIT 4
```

see this [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/64a32/5/0)

If you happen to have multiple rows with same product_no (and same color) in Thinker2014 table and you wanted to return 4 different colors for the same product `HP74` for example, you could use the query below

```
SELECT T.Product_No,T.miniImageFarm,
       @row := IF (@prevProductNo IS NULL OR @prevProductNo != T.Product_No,1,@row+1) as row,
       @prevProductNo := T.Product_No
FROM Thinker2014 T
INNER JOIN SignUp S ON LEFT(T.Product_No,4) = LEFT(S.Product_No,4)
WHERE T.Product_No != S.Product_No
  AND S.User_Id = $user_id
HAVING row = 1
ORDER BY T.Product_No
LIMIT 4;
```

see [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0fe20/2/0)
What the query above does is `ORDER BY T.Product_No` so that it scans through each Product_No so that all the same colours are right after another (for example scans through 3 rows of Cyan, then 8 rows of Magenta, then 5 rows of Yellow for product HP74)
The `@row` variable gets set to 1 whenever it sees a new Product_No value (meaning when our `@prevProductNo` IS NULL when it hasn't been set to anything yet or if it's sees a new Product_No) and counting upwards 2,3 for Cyan then 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 for Magenta, then 1,2,3,4,5 for Yellow for example and we call this value for each row as `row`.
the `HAVING row = 1` meaning we only want rows that have row value of 1 so it'll grab a row 1 of the Cyan colour a row 1 of the Magenta colour and a row 1 of Yellow color. If there are more colours it'll grab row 1 of each color. so then the query will grab different colours. and the LIMIT 4 will just return maximum of 4 entries (of different colors).

And the below query will match first 4 characters and ending in the same characters for example `;HEW` or `;CPT` depending upon Product_No from signup table.

```
SELECT T.Product_No,T.miniImageFarm,
 @row := IF (@prevProductNo IS NULL OR @prevProductNo != T.Product_No,1,@row+1) as row,
 @prevProductNo := T.Product_No
FROM Thinker2014 T
INNER JOIN SignUp S ON T.Product_No LIKE CONCAT(LEFT(S.Product_No,4),'%;',SUBSTRING_INDEX(S.Product_No,';',-1))
WHERE T.Product_No != S.Product_No
 AND S.User_Id = $user_id
HAVING row = 1
ORDER BY T.Product_No
LIMIT 4;
```

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/08b3c/4/0)

Comment: Thank You Tin Tran...the first one worked and provided 4 product_no that were all the same...the second one did not work b/c of the "someIdColumn", I didn't understand. All in all, the fact that the script was accepted makes me feel like a mountain was climbed.  Was the INNER JOIN eligible?  That fact that you turn the $user_id = 2 into the product_no of SignUp using a subquery rather than an INNER JOIN with the Table: Thinker2014 is phenomenal.  How can I learn more of SQL or what book besides the Dummie one or Oreilly might you recommend.  I welcome you to email me: info@inks-etc.com

Comment: it works so long as the SELECT in the subquery returns only one row, if the subquery returns 2 or more rows it breaks that's why i mentioned about the 2nd query with a LIMIT 1 and order by `someIdColumn` from your signup table if you have an auto_increment id column there. so that it guarantees 1 row and will always work.

Comment: If you want to learn more SQL just search for MySQL tags here on SO, they solve specific problems that people run into and you get to learn alot from reading the questions and answers.

Comment: see the very bottom of my answer, it has an INNER JOIN solution if that's what you prefer.

Comment: Wait you said it "provided 4 product_no that were all the same"? Is that a problem? Do you have repeated values in `Thinker2014` and you want all 4 to start with HP74 but have different ending(representing all different colours) from each other?

Comment: If you have repeated values like multiple entries `HP74BC;HEW` and multiple entries of `HP74M;HEW` and multiple entries of `HP74Y;HEW` and multiple entries of `HP74C;HEW` in Thinker2014 table. and you wanted to return 4 different entries (like each one with a different colour) instead of 4 entries that all show `HP74BC;HEW` for example, we can do that too. let me know if that's what you want.

Comment: Updated my answer to include a query with the use of @variables so that you are guaranteed to get different colours of the same product HP74 for example (If you happen to have multiple entries/rows for each color in Thinker2014).  See the sqlFiddle to see what i mean i have repeated rows of same colors in the data.

Comment: Yes...that is correct Tin Tran.  The Thinker2014 is my SearchEngine in which just one cartridge can belong to 1 to a 100 printers.  So the product: HP74BK;HEW is reptative in the Product_No column but different in the Printer_Model column.  To view goto inks-etc.com and got to the click the login and my username = jason and password = 123; then submit then next page and you will see a 4 repetative Product_No.  How do I donate to your fine service - Tin Tran?  Jason Kraft info@inks-etc.org  Thank You.

Comment: no need to donate i just help people on here with mysql for fun, it's fun collecting reputation points.

Comment: I loggedin and I see `C6614D;CPT` 4 times, i am guessing that's not what you want?

Comment: We could even match first 4 characters(HP74) and ends with `;HEW` if you want to just in case you have something like `HP74BK;CPT` and `HP74BK;HEW` so if you have in signups `HP74BK;HEW` and you only want product_No that starts with `HP74` and ends with `;HEW` we can do that too. Let me know if that's what you want so that the only products we'll show only different in color code like `M`,`C`,`Y`,`BC`

Comment: Thanks Tin Tran.  I am using the SELECT T.Product_No,T.miniImageFarm,
    @row := IF (@prevProductNo IS NULL... yet I am aware of what it is doing.  It is pulling Product_No above the original which is GOOD, but it is NOT letting go of the same Product_No. So I have received Product_No C6614D;CPT 6 times and if I change the LIMIT to 25 I will receive C6614D;HEW 8 times and C6615DN:HEW 7 times.  So its there a way to illuminate repetition or just take the same ONLY one time. Above are the instruction to goto the login to see what I mean

Comment: What I conceptually see Tin Tran is the new column of @prevProductNo: = T.Product_No needs to be in a "SELECT DISTINCT" code?  What do think? - Jason Kraft info@inks-etc.org

Comment: if you use the query with the @row it shouldn't return multiple product_No, did you copy the whole query or just partially, you need that other `@prevProductNo := product_No` line too, you can try DISTINCT. but do you want the ;CPT ones if user has ;HEW in signup?

Comment: Yes... And I promise you, it will not work without the @prevProductNo := product_No in part of the sql. You made that as the new column the HAVING takes Product_No from - Jason Kraft

Comment: i just updated my answer with a different query that tries to match the ending of Product_No as well. see if that's what you want. It should return products that have same starting characters and same ending characters and only different in color. Make you copy the whole query for it to work it needs that `HAVING row = 1` line.

Comment: What would you like me to change?

Comment: nothing needs changing if you copied the whole query it should only return different colors of the same starting 4 characters and ending with same ;HEW with the last query i posted.

Comment: you can try looking the sqlFiddle I provided, it doesn't return repetitive product_No, only different ones.

Comment: I analyzed the sqlFiddle and it provided all of the different values needing the program to offer other colors.  There are just too many of the same product being delivered.  I have noticed that programs have personalities and they work when they feel like it.  I am going to the gym to work off my sql frustrations.  You are GREAT!  I am sorry if I let you down.  When I come back, I will con't to find an answer to what you have provided me.  Sincerely Jason Kraft  P.S. Give me me what Printer Model you have and I will provide you a webpage full of Printer Ink  send it here: info@inks-etc.org

Comment: Have fun at the gym. I don't have a printer.